# VSTO Outlook: Apply a color to the cells of a custom View column

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I am trying to add a new column (it is of type text only) to the inbox folder view and I am wondering if it is possible to apply a custom different color to each cell (foreground and background). I have had a look at the view's XML definition which in fact is an XML file. In the columns I have added I have typed the attributes background-color and color within the style tag but it seems it is not working. It seems that it can be achieved by using conditional formatting as the ones already defined for unread messages, etc. but I don't want to apply the color to the entire row, only to some cells of the column. I haven't tried yet using conditional formatting, I don't know if it is possible programmatically, but I would like to avoid this approach. So how can I apply a color to each cell of the column independently?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make such changes manually in Outlook. That is how you can do that - do the required changes manually (if possible) and then you may observe the result in XML. If it is not possible you will not find any way for doing that manually.

The best what you could do is to use a conditional formatting for the view, see [Conditional formatting by Field Criteria with VBA (e.g. From address contains)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ac6113ca-4575-4f05-a7f7-ec2fb611b2cd/conditional-formatting-by-field-criteria-with-vba-eg-from-address-contains?forum=outlookdev) for more information.